# Sorting list of list of elements of a custom class in R?

Tags: r, list, sorting, comparator

I have a custom class object (list of tuples).
I have defined `<.myclass` `>.myclass` and `==.myclass` on it as well.

Now I have a

```
a <- obj1 # of myclass
b <- obj2 # of myclass
c <- obj3 # of myclass
L <- list(list(a,12,1),list(b,215,23),list(c,21,9))
```

I want to sort L, on index 1. i.e. I have `b < c < a` then, I want sorted L in this form `list(list(b,215,23),list(c,21,9),list(a,12,1))`

How do I achieve this?

In my searches, I found how to sort on particular index, and using that I wrote the following function

```
magic_sort <- function(lst, sortind, dec = T) {
    return(lst[order(sapply(lst,'[[',sortind), decreasing = dec)])
}
```

But when I give index 1 to it, to sort on obj1, it fails with

```
> magic_sort(L,1)
Error in order(sapply(lst, "[[", sortind), decreasing = dec) : 
    unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
```

Is there any fix for this? In general, can I have functions like sort, minimum and so on, based on custom definition of comparison operators?

Edit: Following perhaps will help understand the structure better: http://pastebin.com/0M7JRLTu

Edit 2:

```
library("sets")

a <- list()
class(a) <- "dfsc"
a[[1]] <- tuple(1L, 2L, "C", "a", "B")

b <- list()
class(b) <- "dfsc"
b[[1]] <- tuple(1L, 2L, "A", "b", "B")

c <- list()
class(c) <- "dfsc"
c[[1]] <- tuple(1L, 2L, "A", "a", "B")

L <- list()
L[[1]] <- list(a, 12, 132)
L[[2]] <- list(b, 21, 21)
L[[3]] <- list(c, 32, 123)

`<.dfsc` <- function(c1, c2) {
    return(lt_list(toList(c1),toList(c2)))
}

`==.dfsc` <- function(c1, c2) {
    return(toString(c1) == toString(c2))
}

`>.dfsc` <- function(c1, c2) {
    return(!((c1 < c2) || (c1 == c2)))
}

lt_list <- function(l1, l2) {
    n1 <- length(l1)
    n2 <- length(l2)
    j = 1
    while(j <= n1 && j <= n2) {
        if (l1[[j]] != l2[[j]]) {
            return (l1[[j]] < l2[[j]])
        }
        j = j + 1
    }
    return(n1 < n2)
}

toString.dfsc <- function(x) {
    code_string <- ""
    #for(ii in x[[1]]) {
    for(ii in x) {   
        code_string <- paste(code_string,"(",ii[[1]],",",ii[[2]],",",ii[[3]],",",ii[[4]],",",ii[[5]],")", sep = "")
    }
    return(code_string)
}
```

Now I want the `L` desired to be `list(list(c,_,_),list(b,_,_),list(a,_,_))`

Comment: "I want to sort L, on obj1." It's ambiguous what that means. Please provide a reproducible example and show the expected output.

Comment: I clarified a bit. I hope it is not ambiguous anymore. Basically I want to sort on first index, (that is on objects of myclass), for which I have a comparison operator implemented.

Comment: Please clarify by providing *a reproducible example*.

Comment: Giving "reproducible example" is hard without giving explicit definitions of classes and so on. I don't see what is the confusion in understanding "sort on index 1" of a multi dimentional list. Objects in index 1 are of fixed class, and on this class there is a comparison implemented. I want to now sort the entire list, based on the order between first indices of individual lists.

Comment: You are free to ignore my advice. I don't like providing untested code. For testing I need a reproducible example and if creating that is hard, why should I do that work? Also, it's not obvious why your code doesn't work. I have a suspicion, but without a way to reproduce this, I can't check and investigate.

Comment: Check this out: `x <- 1:5; 
class(x) <- "myclass"; 
class(sapply(list(x, x), "[[", 1))`

Comment: Please check the pastebin, as well as part in "Edit 2" where I've tried to give shortest possible extract of definitions required. Let me know if there's something missing / unclear.

Comment: I am not sure what I am supposed to do with the piece of code that you have posted, objects of "myclass" are not integers, they are "list of 5-tuples", in which first 2 numbers are integers and next 3 are strings, and order on them is lexicographic.

Comment: Where is `tuple` defined? Also, I believe your problem is that `sapply` calls `simplify2array` which strips the class attributes. That's what my previous comment demonstrates with a "minimal reproducible example". Alternatively, maybe it doesn't simplify, but then you end up with a list and `order` can't handle that.

Comment: Tuple is in `library("sets")` and yes problem is order is not able to produce a permutation from list-vector, but is there no way to sort list of objects of arbitrary class

Comment: You could make `L` also an S3 object and define an `order` generic and method for the class.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515377/sort-a-list-of-nontrivial-elements-in-r) might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7516342/2414948) from Aaron demonstrates, exactly, what is needed to apply a customized `sort` on a `class`ed object. As Roland notes, you -actually- need to `sort` "L" and, thus, that is where the focus on custom `sort` should be. To provide flexibility specifying on which index of "L" 's elements to `sort`, a way would be to store an extra `attr` on "L":

Turn "L" to an appropriate object:

```
class(L) = "myclass"
attr(L, "sort_ind") = 1L
```

`Ops` methods need to be defined (extract the relevant element of your data):

```
"<.myclass" = function(x, y) 
{
    i = attr(x, "sort_ind") ## also check if 'x' and 'y' have the same 'attr(, "sort_ind")'
    x[[1]][[i]] < y[[1]][[i]] 
}
"==.myclass" = function(x, y) 
{
     i = attr(x, "sort_ind")
     x[[1]][[i]] == y[[1]][[i]] 
}
">.myclass" = function(x, y) 
{
    i = attr(x, "sort_ind")
    x[[1]][[i]] > y[[1]][[i]] 
}
```

And a subset method:

```
"[.myclass" = function(x, i) 
{
    y = .subset(x, i)
    attributes(y) = attributes(x)
    return(y)
}
```

The above methods are necessary (perhaps, except `"<"`) to be defined since a call to `sort`/`order` will end up calling `rank` which needs `.gt` in order to subset accordingly each element and compare. 
Finally, a get/set function for sauce:

```
sort_ind = function(x) attr(x, "sort_ind")
"sort_ind<-" = function(x, value) 
{
    attr(x, "sort_ind") = value
    return(x)
}
```

And:

```
order(L)
#[1] 3 2 1
sort_ind(L) = 3
order(L)
#[1] 2 3 1
```

A method for `sort` can be, also, created to wrap all the above:

```
sort.myclass = function(x, sort_ind = attr(x, "sort_ind"), ...)
{
    sort_ind(x) = sort_ind
    NextMethod()
}

sort(L)
sort(L, sort_ind = 1)
```

*(I assumed that your `toList` function would look like something `toList = function(x) x[[1L]]`)*

Comment: Thanks, I saw that answer but I couldn't get the appropriate `'['` defined. With your definition, it works. (It is not exactly clear to me what is the purpose of `[` function). Anyway, I ended up preferring the quicksort solution since I have list of lists, and I can specify which index to sort on etc, and it just gives me much more freedom (and seems "cleaner" approach instead of creating further classes)

Comment: @Hrishikesh : Made an edit to address the option of sorting by specified index. Personally, I find working with "class"es + R's -already- generic functions cleaner than re-building R's functionality with more functions. Here, specifying -only- some `Ops` and `"["` methods, all of `sort`/`order`/`xtfrm`/`rank` and wrappers of them can work appropriately with the object. Also, the functions, above, can be changed to accomodate the actual "L" structure appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make use of internal and supposedly more efficient sort, but doesn't seem like this sort has facility to take custom comparison operator. So I ended up using implementation of quicksort to sort lists of lists at arbitrary index, assuming comparison exists between the elements at that index.

```
part_qsort <- function(l, idx, low, high) {
    lst <- l
    pivot <- lst[[high]][[idx]]
    i <- low - 1

    for(j in low:(high-1)) {
        if ((lst[[j]][[idx]] < pivot) || (lst[[j]][[idx]] == pivot)) {
            i <- i + 1
            swap(lst[[i]],lst[[j]])
        }
    }
    swap(lst[[(i+1)]],lst[[high]])
    eval.parent(substitute(l <- lst))
    return(i+1)
}

# recursive calls to quicksort
qsort <- function(l,idx,low,high) {
    if (low < high) {
        lst <- l
        pi <- part_qsort(lst,idx,low,high)
        qsort(lst, idx, low, pi-1)
        qsort(lst, idx, pi+1, high)
        eval.parent(substitute(l <- lst))
    }
}
```

Another thing to look into can be `library("rlist")` which seems to have a bunch of functions implemented on lists.